# can't run vagrant for laravel homestead

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

i want to use laravel/homestead. i do all steps one by one according to below url
https://medium.com/@eaimanshoshi/i-am-going-to-write-down-step-by-step-procedure-to-setup-homestead-for-laravel-5-2-17491a423aa

but when i send this command -> 'vagrant up' i get these warnings and errors

C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:68: warning: already initialized constant Win32::WCHAR
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:68: warning: previous definition of WCHAR was here
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:69: warning: already initialized constant Win32::WCHAR_NUL
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:69: warning: previous definition of WCHAR_NUL was here
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:70: warning: already initialized constant Win32::WCHAR_CR
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:70: warning: previous definition of WCHAR_CR was here
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:71: warning: already initialized constant Win32::WCHAR_SIZE
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:71: warning: previous definition of WCHAR_SIZE was here
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32/registry.rb:72:in `find': unknown encoding name - CP720 (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 1):

i solved it. these errors was from apps version. i decreased app version to
virtual box 5.1.26 from 5.2.8
vagrant 2.0.0 from 2.0.2

and now every thing is ok

Answer (score 0):

Did you try too reinstal it?

Check your system if there is not a vboxheadless proces going on. Turn it off and try again

Comment: that was for version of apps i can fix it just now